# Conditional Configuration Framework

Tags: configuration, frameworks

I'm searching for a configuration framework which handles key/values pairs based on conditions. The language and storage type doesn't matter.

Example with background color for Application XYZ:

- Application has the background color
  "red".
- On Monday the background color should be green.
- The background color for User XYZ on Monday should be orange.

The developer just ask for something like "application.background.color" and this should return the correct value based on the given conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, have a look at Commons Configuration. You will need to extend it somewhat, but you should be able to use the existing frameworks variable expansion, providing you can define your available context elements in advance.